# Map frequency of occurrences in a Pandas column to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` which has these columns -

```
Quiz          Question         K
  1              1           XYZ-01
  1              2           XXY-07
  1              2           XXP-05
  2              1           PQR-02
  2              1           WXY-09
  2              2           PQR-09
  2              3           XXY-07
  2              3           XXP-05
```

I want to make a dictionary that has all unique combinations of `K`s in the same Quiz as the keys, and their frequency of occurrence as the value. For eg. for the above df, `dict_combinations` should look something like -

```
{('XYZ-01', 'XXY-07'): 2, ('XXY-07', 'XXP-05'): 2, ('XYZ-01', 'XXP-05'): 1,       # for Quiz 1
 ('PQR-02', 'WXY-09'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'PQR-09'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'XXY-07'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'XYZ-01'): 1, # for Quiz 2 
 ('WXY-09', 'PQR-09'): 1, ('WXY-09', 'XXY-07'): 1, ('WXY-09', 'XXP-05'): 1, ('PQR-09', 'XXY-07'): 1,
 ('PQR-09', 'XXP-05'): 1}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @jezrael because that combination of `K`s occurs two times, once in Quiz 1 and once in Quiz 2.

Comment: Yes, sorry! Corrected now!

Comment: And it seems `('XYZ-01', 'XXY-07'): 2` should be `('XYZ-01', 'XXY-07'): 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove possible missing values, then [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and create combinations of `2` per groups in lambda function, flatten nested tuples by [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and last count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with convert to dictionary:

```
from  itertools import combinations

d = (df.dropna(subset=['K'])
        .sort_values(['Quiz','K'])
        .groupby('Quiz')['K'].apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))
        .explode()
        .value_counts()
        .to_dict()
        )
print (d)
{('XXP-05', 'XXY-07'): 2, ('WXY-09', 'XXY-07'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'PQR-09'): 1,
 ('PQR-09', 'WXY-09'): 1, ('XXY-07', 'XYZ-01'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'XXY-07'): 1,
 ('PQR-09', 'XXP-05'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'WXY-09'): 1, ('PQR-09', 'XXY-07'): 1, 
 ('WXY-09', 'XXP-05'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'XXP-05'): 1, ('XXP-05', 'XYZ-01'): 1}
```

Another idea is use `Counter` for dictionary:

```
from  itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

L = [tuple(sorted(y)) for i,x in df.dropna(subset=['K']).groupby('Quiz') 
                      for y in combinations(x['K'], 2)]
d = dict(Counter(L))
print (d)
{('XXY-07', 'XYZ-01'): 1, ('XXP-05', 'XYZ-01'): 1, ('XXP-05', 'XXY-07'): 2, 
 ('PQR-02', 'WXY-09'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'PQR-09'): 1, ('PQR-02', 'XXY-07'): 1, 
 ('PQR-02', 'XXP-05'): 1, ('PQR-09', 'WXY-09'): 1, ('WXY-09', 'XXY-07'): 1, 
 ('WXY-09', 'XXP-05'): 1, ('PQR-09', 'XXY-07'): 1, ('PQR-09', 'XXP-05'): 1}
```

EDIT: How working `explode` here:

It flatten nested lists of tuples in `Series`:

```
s = (df.dropna(subset=['K'])
        .sort_values(['Quiz','K'])
        .groupby('Quiz')['K'].apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))
        # .explode()
        # .value_counts()
        # .to_dict()
        )
print (s)
Quiz
1    [(XXP-05, XXY-07), (XXP-05, XYZ-01), (XXY-07, ...
2    [(PQR-02, PQR-09), (PQR-02, WXY-09), (PQR-02, ...
Name: K, dtype: object
```

---

```
s = (df.dropna(subset=['K'])
        .sort_values(['Quiz','K'])
        .groupby('Quiz')['K'].apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))
        .explode()
        )
print (s)
Quiz
1    (XXP-05, XXY-07)
1    (XXP-05, XYZ-01)
1    (XXY-07, XYZ-01)
2    (PQR-02, PQR-09)
2    (PQR-02, WXY-09)
2    (PQR-02, XXP-05)
2    (PQR-02, XXY-07)
2    (PQR-09, WXY-09)
2    (PQR-09, XXP-05)
2    (PQR-09, XXY-07)
2    (WXY-09, XXP-05)
2    (WXY-09, XXY-07)
2    (XXP-05, XXY-07)
Name: K, dtype: object
```

Comment: The first method works. Is there a way to remove dictionary entries where one of the tuple element is `nan` ? Some of the rows in my dataframe are `nan`...

Comment: @harry04 - Then use `df = df.dropna(subset=['K'])` before my solution for remove rows with missing values in `K`

Comment: Awesome! That works for me. Thanks! Can you tell me how does `explode()` work here?

Comment: @harry04 - Added to answer.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! :)